# Filetype specific maps in MacVim (with vundle)

Tags: r, vim

I wish to map `<D-1>` to `<-` when i'm editing `R` files.

I initially edited `~/.vim/bundle/Vim-R-plugin/ftdetect/r.vim` and added:

```
inoremap <D-1> <space><-<space>
```

However it was available when i was editing all types of files -- i tested `.py` and my `.vimrc`.

Why does this occur?

To fix the problem, i added:

```
autocmd FileType r inoremap <D-1> <space><-<space>
```

to my `.vimrc`. Now the map is not there when i initially open mvim, however once i've opened an `*.r` file, the mapping exists for all my other files.

To test what was going on, i added:

```
autocmd FileType python inoremap <D-1> <space>==<space>
```

and found that when i had loaded neither type of file, `<D-1>` wasn't mapped; that when i loaded an `*.r` file, that `<D-1>` gave me `<-` (as desired) in `*.r` files, as well as in *all* other files -- and when i next opened an `*.py` file, that `<D-1>` yielded `==` in *all* files -- including in the `*.r` files.

Experimenting, i found that whatever file type i had most recently opened would define the mapping.  This is undesirable behaviour when editing more than one filetype.

What is the *best practice* solution to this problem?

I use MacVim and manage my bundles with vundle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As sylvain.joyeux mentioned in his answer you should use 'ftplugin' directory for your mappings. But this won't solve mapping issues. The reason why `<D-1>` mapping is available for all buffers is that you define it for all buffers (globally). If you want to limit a mapping to some particular buffer you should use `<buffer>` special argument of `:map` commands. So your mapping command should look like this:

```
inoremap <buffer> <D-1> <space><-<space>
```

See `:help :map-<buffer>` for details.

Comment: +1 & accepted -- thanks v much. Just one quibble, `:help :map-buffer` doesn't work on MacVim. What i found was `:help :map-<buffer>` which seemed on topic. Is there a way of adding a `personal` file to my ftplugin directory - for i fear that vundle will update over my edits to the `r.vim` file in that directory.  For this reason, i'm considering putting it back into my `.vimrc`.

Comment: I forgot to add angle brackets, fixed it. You can place the mapping to some other directory (I usually put custom things to `~/.vim/ftplugin/type.vim`) or leave in `.vimrc`. I use pathogen and I don't know what is the best way of handling this with vundle (it could be creating a repository with custom settings).

Comment: +1, for the `~/.vim/ftplugin/type.vim` tip. thanks very much.  you know, i Googled this issue a lot, and none of the answers i found - including a few on SO - had the `<buffer>` caveat. that plus the `~/.vim/ftplugin/type.vim` is gold.

Answer (score 0):

The ftdetect directory is meant to hold files that register file autodetection commands, i.e. usually of the form

```
au BufNewFile,BufRead *.antlr setf antlr
```

the ftplugin directory is the one that you were looking for. However, I am not sure whether adding r.vim here would not override any globally-available R plugin (if there is one, I am not sure about that)

Comment: Defining multiple ftplugins for same file type makes Vim to load all of defined scripts. So none of them will override another one **unless** two or more plugins contain `b:did_ftplugin` guard.

Comment: i moved the `autocmd BufNewFile,BufRead *.r inoremap <D-1> <space><-<space>` and left the python version in my `.vimrc` and i still get the precedence problem -- ie the most recently opened file type _defines_ the mapping.